# Trigger next stage of pipeline after previous stage is successful

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have Stage 1 and Stage2 in Jenkins Pipeline. I have python script in Stage 1 which create some file or print output on console. I want Stage 2 to be triggered when this file exist or found output on console.

Stage 1 output will be always successful.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Run stage only if previous stage was successful in Jenkins Scripted Pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53638340/run-stage-only-if-previous-stage-was-successful-in-jenkins-scripted-pipeline)

Comment: the above link might not solve the complete issue but head start for dependant stage example.

Comment: You can set a conditional on stage 2 dependent upon the output of your script.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a trigger per se, but you can use a when clause in the stage you want to conditionaly build:

```
stages{
    stage('Stage1'){
        steps{
            //pythonbuild
        }
    }
    stage('Stage2'){
        when{
            expression{
                return fileExists('file')
            }
        }
        steps{
            //conditionalbuild
        }
    }
}
```

See [official docs](https://jenkins.io/blog/2017/01/19/converting-conditional-to-pipeline/#longer-pipeline)